# What are the citation "best practices" when converting a mailing list discussion into a Q&A SO post?

Tags: discussion

I was searching for an answer to a technical question about a programming tool, and found the best answer in an [old email list posting](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/vgxkDSgOnlc), rather than on StackOverflow, where I'd hoped to find it.

I think the SO community would benefit from having the information I found. I'd like to convert the information into a Q&A based SO post (cleaned up and edited), but want to make sure I properly cite the original authors, and if necessary, get whatever permission I should get before hand.

Are there existing guidelines for addressing this sort of goal?

Comment: Nice Q. I'm not a programmer, but I'm a bit active in ELL and Chem.SE. When I cite something like this, I usually paraphrase it using "X". And then give credit to the authors by indicating that `this was paraphrased from `[here](the link)  .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the guidelines in [How to reference material written by others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)

> - Provide a link to the original page or answer
> - Quote only the relevant portion
> - Provide the name of the original author

Comment: I downvoted this answer for experimental purposes only.

Comment: @georgechalhoub lol. I hope your experiment went well ;)