# Unanswered section does not include questions with negatively scored answers

Tags: bug, unanswered-questions

On each Stack Exchange site, you find an [UNANSWERED](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) section where all unanswered questions or questions with not upvoted answers with be listed.

In a blog post [Ok, now define](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/) answered. You said:

> As of today, here’s how we do it:
>
> - **Answered Questions** have at least one answer with one upvote (or
>   accepted)
> - **Unanswered Questions** have no answers with upvotes (or accepted)

However, you forgot to include unanswered questions with downvoted answers to the **Unanswered Questions** instead, the system is labelling them as **Answered Questions** though the answers are downvoted.

I detected the bug when trying to answer a member's question on [meta skeptics](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3081/why-doesnt-this-question-show-up-in-the-unanswered-questions-list). It seems also the member had open [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247373/unanswered-question-does-not-show-up-in-unanswered-questions-list) about it  on this meta site.

Live experiment, when viewing [unanswered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/unanswered) questions:

David's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251051/what-are-the-citation-best-practices-when-converting-a-mailing-list-discussion) had a vote of 0:

> [image]

Then I went to downvote David's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251051/what-are-the-citation-best-practices-when-converting-a-mailing-list-discussion), it had a -1 now:

> [image]

Surprisingly it got removed from the list, and it shouldn't since it is unanswered.

Comment: I'm sorry if I caused some misclarification, all clear now.

Comment: Can you include a link to that question?

Comment: I added a link in the question, someone has upvoted it again however. Make sure you downvote it (and wait a few minutes) to notice the bug.

Comment: @AnnaLear You can look at [this question](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/22476/would-humans-starve-if-spiders-disappeared) - it has one answer that is negatively scored, and it doesn't appear in the Skeptics [Unanswered Questions](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/unanswered) list.

Comment: It seems the bug is fixed.

Comment: Not fixed (anymore) -  [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2937/story-where-the-number-3-is-the-monster) isn't in [the unanswered list](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=votes)

Comment: @Kevin: bug on skeptics were fixed. It seems the bug is still alive on scifi.se...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Up-voted question with down-voted answers not listed as "Unanswered"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256036/up-voted-question-with-down-voted-answers-not-listed-as-unanswered)